# US tourist visa for a friend in Kosovo?

Tags: visas, usa, invitation-letters, kosovo

I am a U.S citizen and I have a friend from Kosovo that I met online.
I have met him twice when I went there to visit.

I want him to get a tourist visa so he can come here in the U.S and meet my family. So basically, his reason for visit will be tourism and to visit a friend.

He is 24 years old and he lives with his parents. They have a business and he also works at a store. 
He will most likely stay in the U.S for about 2-3 weeks, if he is granted the visa, and I will help him with his expenses when he's here in the U.S.

What are the chances that he'll be granted a tourist visa?
How does he show proof that I will help him with the expenses?

Comment: Is this friend a romantic interest? (It matters.)

Comment: yes it is. we plan to apply for the fiance visa in the future.